# Target .net framework 2.0 in Visual Studio 2015 Express Web

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express

I've recently installed VS 2015 Express Web to do some asp.net development for an intranet platform running .net 2.  Upgrading this platform is not an option, so I'd like to target v2 in my VS project, but the option will not present:

[image: New Project Dialogue]

I'm running Windows 7, so installing .net 3.5 sp 1 via the MS installer @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=22 or https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25150 is not an option - the installer directs me to use Add/Remove Windows Features from Programs and Features in the Control Panel:

Add/Remove Windows Features Dialogue
[image]

I had .net 3.5.1 installed before installing VS.  Advice from Google lead me to uninstall/reinstall it, and run the VS repair option from its installer, but I still have no option to target .net 2 in the New Project dialogue.  I have seen screenshots in threads around the 'net showing earlier .net versions in the dialogue box so I'm hopeful that there is some way to make this work.

Can you please let me know what I'm missing, or some way to resolve this problem?

Thanks very much!

Comment: To be able to target 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5 using VS 2015, you should install the 3.5 Sp1 framework from the installation page

Comment: Already went down that path, and noted why it's not possible in my question: "I'm running Windows 7, so installing .net 3.5 sp 1 via the MS installer @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=22 or https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25150 is not an option - the installer directs me to use Add/Remove Windows Features from Programs and Features in the Control Panel"

Comment: did you checked it ? and tried?

Comment: As I wrote, those installers direct me to use the Add/Remove Windows Features to install .net 3.5 sp 1.

Comment: after adding those features , you will able to see the target framework 2

Comment: I tried adding the sub-features, restarted, repaired VS, and restarted again. Unfortunately, I still can't select framework versions < 4.

Comment: [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says "In Express editions of Visual Studio, you cannot set the target framework in the New Project dialog box." it seems to suggest that by *opening* an earlier project you can upgrade it or leave the target as is. not sure if that actually works though.

Comment: [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_existing) says: "In Express editions of Visual Studio, you must create the project first, and then you can change the target..."

Comment: @wazz, you got it.  When I go to change the target .net version after creating the project I have access to the earlier versions.  Not the optimal situation, but better than nothing.  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it within a couple days if no one comes in with some way of selecting the earlier versions at project creation.

Comment: @Yllzarith done. tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says

> In Express editions of Visual Studio, you cannot set the target
>   framework in the New Project dialog box." it seems to suggest that by
>   opening an earlier project you can upgrade it or leave the target as
>   is. not sure if that actually works though.

[this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_existing) says:

> In Express editions of Visual Studio, you must create the project
>   first, and then you can change the target...